# Achieving a smooth color ramp

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, heatmap

I have heat map in Excel that im trying to recreate in R. Its basically data for an RFM segmentation and in excel the color range is great but im struggling to get such a nice smooth color gradient in R and have tried numerous ways but cannot achieve the same smooth gradient.

My Excel heatmap looks like this:

[image]

My heatmap in R looks like this:

[image]

My R code is:

```
cols <- brewer.pal(9, 'RdYlGn')

ggplot(xxx)+
  geom_tile(aes(x= mon, y = reorder(freq, desc(freq)), fill = n)) + 

facet_grid(rec~.) +
#  geom_text(aes(label=n)) +

# scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = (max(xxx$n)/2), low = "red", mid = 
"yellow", high = "darkgreen") +
# scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue") +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = cols) +
# scale_fill_brewer() +

labs(x = "monetary", y= "frequency") +
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
coord_fixed(ratio= 0.5) +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

How can I apply `ColorRampPalette` to achieve the same smooth color gradient as in Excel or any othe method that gives me a smoother gradient? The gradient in R is not very nice.

I cannot post my data set here as it it has 30,000 records. Im using dput(head(df)) do dump the head of my data set below:

```
structure(list(rfm_score = c(111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 121), n = c(2624L, 
160L, 270L, 23L, 5L, 650L), rec = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    freq = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), mon = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = 
"factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just a note, for your use case, [DT package](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) might be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tableHTML` package:

This is the data I am using:

```
df <- structure(list(rfm_score = c(111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 121), n = c(2624L, 
                                                                  160L, 270L, 23L, 5L, 650L), rec = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
               freq = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
                                                                      "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), mon = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = 
                                                                                                                                "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                          6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Load the package:

```
library(tableHTML)
```

Reshape the `data.frame` to reflect the structure you have:

```
df <- data.table::dcast(df, 
                        rec + freq ~ mon,
                        value.var = "rfm_score",
                        fill = "")

  rec freq   1   2   3   4   5
1   1    1 111 112 113 114 115
2   1    2 121
```

You can then create a `tableHTML` object and apply css to it to adjust the style:
The steps are these:

1. Create `tableHTML` object with second headers and caption
2. add background colour and border to caption
3. Change background colour of second header `"Mon."`
4. add a colour rank to the `rec` and `freq` column using the RColorbrewer palette `"Blues"`
5. make sure missing values (i.e. `""`) are white
6. Apply `RAG` (Red, Amber, Green) colour rank to `Mon.` columns
7. Apply different shades of blue to the headers below `Mon.`

\

```
df %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE, 
            second_headers = list(c(2, 5),
                                  c("", "Mon.")),
            caption = "<br>RFM Segmentation <br> Count of Cust in each Segment",
            widths = c(rep(80, 2), rep(100, 5))) %>% 
  add_css_caption(css = list(c("background-color", "border"),
                             c("#F9E9DC", "1px solid black"))) %>% 
  add_css_second_header(css = list("background-color",
                                   "lightgray"),
                        second_headers = 2) %>% 
  add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "colour_rank",
                             colour_rank_css = make_css_colour_rank_theme(list(rec = df$rec),
                                                                          RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Blues")),
                             columns = 1) %>% 
  add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "colour_rank",
                             colour_rank_css = make_css_colour_rank_theme(list(freq = df$freq),
                                                                          RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Blues")),
                             columns = 2) %>% 
  add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "==",
                             value = "",
                             css = list(c("background-color", "color"),
                                        c("white", "white")),
                             columns = 3:7) %>% 
  add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "colour_rank",
                             colour_rank_theme = "RAG",
                             columns = 3:7,
                             decreasing = TRUE) %>% 
  add_css_header(css = list("background-color",
                            "#EFF3FF"),
                 header = 3) %>% 
  add_css_header(css = list("background-color",
                            "#BDD7E7"),
                 header = 4) %>% 
  add_css_header(css = list("background-color",
                            "#6BAED6"),
                 header = 5) %>% 
  add_css_header(css = list("background-color",
                            "#3182BD"),
                 header = 6) %>% 
  add_css_header(css = list("background-color",
                            "#08519C"),
                 header = 7)
```

The result looks like this:

[image: output]

Comment: HI clemens, Thank you so much for your time and effort, I really appreciate this. It looks amazing.

Comment: When I reproduce your example, i get the following error:  Error in tableHTML(., rownames = FALSE, second_headers = list(c(2, 5),  : 
  widths must have the same length as the columns

Comment: Ok so I have created the heatmap with the full data set (30,0000 records and it looks good, but the color scale is completely wrong. Dont know how to upload a pic in the secondary comment boxes. Any ideas how I can load a pic in these commentary boxes so you can see the output

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. This is a bit of a bug that you have discovered, I have logged it on GitHub and started working on a solution. Will let you know as soon as I have a workaround!

Comment: I have looked into the issue and I am not sure what you mean when you say that the scale is wrong. Could you share the result you get and the result you would expect? (Maybe as a link to shared drive?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178077/discussion-between-clemens-and-heinrich-muller).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `gradientn()` will make a linear color scale. Looking at your example done in Excel, a value of 1 is displayed as red, 200 as yellow, and 2000 in green. I don't know how Excel is scaling that (I would guess percentiles?), but it's definitely not linear.

If the linear value is what matters and transforming this data would be inappropriate, then the color scale in Excel is misleading. It looks like there is a pretty wide distribution of values, but in reality, most of your values are similar and thus pretty low, as shown in the `ggplot2` color scales.

If log transforming the values is reasonable or appropriate, then do that. That would give you a similar scale to what Excel is giving, but it would be much more clear to the viewer.

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(123) ; rn = rnorm(25, mean = 5, sd = 2)

df = data.frame(monetary = rep(seq(5),5),
                frequency = sort(rep(seq(5),5)),
                val = 10^rn)

pal = brewer.pal(9, "RdYlGn")

# mostly red, a few green (very high) values
ggplot(df, aes(monetary, frequency)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = val)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal)

# log transforming evens out scale
ggplot(df, aes(monetary, frequency)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = log10(val))) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal)
```

Comment: Hi Tyr,  yes, this seems to make a big difference.  Thank you